# XNA 4.0 free e-books

Tags: c#, wpf, xna

Does anybody know some XNA 4.0 papers. I'm interested in e-books and other documents/papers. Preferably free....

Non-common websites are also welcome :)  (Not returned from google search)

Comment: where do you think we find them? :)

Comment: i.e. .NET users groups... like yours... Somebody created good presentation and shares is just with the group.... for others it's hard to keep eye on all websites in the net. That's why i've raised my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Charles Petzold's new Windows Phone 7 book covers XNA on the phone, that might be useful.

Free download from his site here: http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html

Comment: Certainly not. And this is not the same link. The other answer linked to a blog post about a book without saying who wrote the book. I was not aware until now that this was refering to the same book. My link is direct to the author's site so I think it's a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft](https://web.archive.org/web/20150118050352/http://create.msdn.com:80/en-US/education/catalog) have updated all of the Education catalog to be version 4.  I'd start there.  At this present time, I don't think that there are any Game Studio 4 books.  Maybe only available on pre-order.

[Shawn Hargreaves](https://web.archive.org/web/20140420072125/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/10/28/free-e-book-by-charles-petzold.aspx) blogged about a free e-book, but I believe it's more for Windows Phone 7 development.